# Github API Specify Previous Tag

Tags: github, github-api, github-release

I'm trying to figure out how to specify "Previous Tag" via queryparams in the release form automation, or via the Create Release API. Preferably **Both**.

Here is the feature in the UI [documented as step 7 here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository).

[image: previous tag for generated release notes]

If there is no way to do this - where does one request a feature for github? Ex: Is there a github project for github?

Here are the documentation pages for the two ways to do this:

- [Automation for release forms](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/automation-for-release-forms-with-query-parameters) - there is no "previous_tag" option.
- [Create a release API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#create-a-release) - there is no obvious reference to how to specify previous tag, even though there is a way to specify and tell it to generate release notes.

To repeat the question one more time:

How do we specify the specify the prerelease tag for release note autogen? - if unavailable, where does one request a feature for github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

There is a separate [API for generating the release notes](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#generate-release-notes-content-for-a-release), which accepts the `previous_tag` parameter.

For the querystring, a [feature request is open](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/29048) in the github feedback board. Vote for it go give it visbility, hopefully GitHub will take note and implement it.

**Original Answer:**

It does not look like you can configure it via queryparameters or the API yet. The documentation you shared seems to confirm that.

GitHub has an [open discussion board](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions) where you can propose features and they have previously shown that they work on topics that resound with the community.

I don't see a fitting category for "Releases" right now, but you can probably fit it into the categories [`APIs and Integrations`](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/categories/apis-and-integrations) or [`General`](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/categories/general).

Comment: Awesome thanks! I also found that there is an API to generate release notes with accepts the previous_tag. So you'd have to use this separately, then post the resulting body to the create_release endpoint. If you like to add this to your answer, it would be a pretty end-to-end response.

Comment: Added a community request: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/29048 Thanks!

Comment: @TheJeff Added an update to the original answer. Thanks for sharing!